# how to cancel mongoose query 'save' 'pre' hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i want cancel the insert if there was an error hashing the password using bcrypt

```
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    try {
        const hashedPassWord = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10)
        this.password = haschedpassword
    } catch (err) {
        // samething like rollback in sql database
    }

    next()

})
```

Answer (score 0):

[Erros in pre hooks](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#error-handling)

> If any pre hook errors out, mongoose will not execute subsequent middleware or the hooked function. Mongoose will instead pass an error to the callback and/or reject the returned promise. There are several ways to report an error in middleware:

```
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  const err = new Error('something went wrong');
  // If you call `next()` with an argument, that argument is assumed to be
  // an error.
  next(err);
});

schema.pre('save', function() {
  // You can also return a promise that rejects
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject(new Error('something went wrong'));
  });
});

schema.pre('save', function() {
  // You can also throw a synchronous error
  throw new Error('something went wrong');
});

schema.pre('save', async function() {
  await Promise.resolve();
  // You can also throw an error in an `async` function
  throw new Error('something went wrong');
});

// later...

// Changes will not be persisted to MongoDB because a pre hook errored out
myDoc.save(function(err) {
  console.log(err.message); // something went wrong
});
```

## TL;DR

Just pass anything to `next` or throw an error

In your case removing `try..catch` will do